# Can NMF assign probabilities to the topics it outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, topic-models, non-negative-matrix-factorization

It's my understanding that only LDA can assign probabilities to words within each topic that it discovers since it's a probabilistic graphical model

politicians 0.05 united states 0.10 obama 0.20 presidents 0.30 etc

and NMF never outputs probabilities with the topics because the model is entire based on linear algebra matrix factorization. Is this correct or can NMF output probabilities as well?

Answer (score 0):

NMF provides weights. I’m not sure if these weights can be normalized and considered to be probabilities, but they can be used in a similar manner to identify more and less likely/weighted. The question would be if LDA is well-calibrated and if NMF weights could be used in a manner that ranks things in a well-calibrated way.

How do you intend to use the results of LDA or NMF?

Comment: thank you for your response. I am trying to get counts for every topic (as in count in how many documents the topic consisting of the n words appears out of the dataset)